# What does this PL/SQL statement means?

Tags: oracle

Sorry for the silly question... :)

I found this statement in a query:

select * from table a, table b
**WHERE a.id =b.id(+)**

What does the plus between brackets mean?

Thank you

Comment: it's an outer join

Comment: It is proprietary Oracle syntax for left outer join, dating from before the ANSI SQL standards. The LEFT OUTER JOIN syntax (with the join condition in an ON clause, not in the WHERE clause) is preferred and strongly encouraged even by Oracle. (However, Oracle has some nasty bugs where the ANSI syntax is not understood! Not many though, and you will be much more advanced before you will run into them.)

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is outer join and this query is equal to -
`SELECT
 A.ID,
 B.anycol
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID`